# Iframe keeps refreshing on all actions (scroll, click, ect)

Tags: angular, pdf, iframe, frontend

```
    <dxi-item *ngFor="let file of fileList">
        <iframe [src]="dom.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(appInfo.getServerUrl()+'/not/important/'+appInfo.sessionInfo.companyId.toString() + '/' +file.repoId.toString())"></iframe>
    </dxi-item>
```

Anything I render inside of this iframe will continually rerender when i interact with the webpage at all... wondering how to prevent this continuous rerendering.

Comment: Could you put your code on StackBlitz? Need more information like how you generate fileList etc.

Comment: File list contains a repositoryId which I send to my API (last part of the [src]).  The API serves up a file from the repo to be displayed in the browsers iframe (png, pdf, ect).  Nothing else is interacting with the iframe.  I assume the [src] keeps reloading the file on page events is whats happening so is there any way to stop those events / stop the reloads?

Comment: If src value gets reassigned/updated then it will be rendered again. I can't tell without knowing more information. share you TS code